# Weird behaviour in chrome object console.log

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I try to console.log an object in Chrome, it states in the first line of the console.log (where you see Object { small summary here } that my posts array is of length 0 (posts: Array[0]).

However when I expand the post it shows that it has 27 items in it (which is what I need).

This happens to me randomly and I got no idea why it is happening, anybody experienced this before?

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Update: This happens in all browsers, so it is probably not chrome related

Comment: My best guess is that it originally has 0 items, but then the object is updated, so it shows the new version upon expansion.

Comment: I tried that before and when I do: console.log(JSON.stringify()); then all the posts are in it too. But when I try to access it it is not able to find any posts.

Comment: Yeah the console does that. Like mentioned it must have been zero at the time of printing but it probably goes through the data again. Same happen for an object which is printed and then used and emptied out. The console will show it has what you used in  it but if you extend the object it can be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger can't know if an object has been altered, this is why the `posts` attribute's rendering (in your example) has not been updated. Even if the debugger would be able to know when a attribute has been changed updating it every time (and all "loggings") would be too expensive.

So the debugger will check the attribute only when accessing it explicitly.

Chrome in this case will do this even only once:

```
p = []; window.x = {x: p}; 
Object {x: Array[0]}
x: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
x.x.push(1);
1
x.x.push(2);
2
```

*Klicking `x`, the Array updates*

```
p = []; window.x = {x: p}; 
Object {x: Array[2]}
x: Array[2]
   0: 1
   1: 2
   length: 2
   __proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

*Adding one item more to the array and toggleing `x` again, the size and entries remain*

```
x.x.push(3)
3


x: Array[2]
   0: 1
   1: 2
   length: 2
   __proto__: Array[0]
```

In my opinion it's not necessary for the logger to update the object value since the *variable watch* has this function already. There you can *always* update the current value of a variable.

This works in Firebug and Chrome. Here's an example for Chrome:

[image: Chrome: how to update variables in debugger watch]

Answer (score 0):

The answer of "try-cache-finally" is correct too but I want to contribute the answer that caused the problem to happen in the first place.

when you have this code:

```
var b = [];
function a(callback) {
   if (b.length > 0) {
       return callback();
   }

   doXhr(function() {
       b.push("something");
   })
}
```

when you now call a twice then the second call will not see the updated a because of the XHR requests still being in process, this causes the xhr request to be called twice.

The solution for this is to wait on the callback for a like this:

```
a(function() {
    a(function() {
        // Correct trigger
    });
});
```

So actually basic async programming, but this error was because of an already existing code base with this bug in it and it was hard to track down.